# Call method inside inner class

Tags: java, methods

```
class aa {
  public void bb() {
    class cc {
      public void dd() {
        System.out.println("hello");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to call `dd()` method in main method?

```
class Solution {
  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    /* i want to call dd() here */    
  }
}
```

Comment: Through an instance of cc, as you do with any other class.

Answer (score 2):

To call an instance method, you need an instance of that method e.g.

```
class aa {
    interface ii {
        public void dd();
    }

    public ii bb() {
        // you can only call the method of a public interface or class
        // as cc implements ii, this allows you to call the method.
        class cc implements ii {
             public void dd() {
                  System.out.println("hello");   
             }
        }
        return new cc();
    }
}
```

later

```
new aa().bb().dd();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class aa {
    public void bb() {

    }

    static class  cc {
        void dd() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cc c = new aa.cc();
        c.dd();
    }
}
```

1. You inner class should be in class aa not in method of class aa
2. And cc class should be static

Answer (score 0):

you can call it using calling bb() call from main like,

```
public static void main(String... s){

    new aa().bb()
}
```

And modify bb()like,

```
public void bb()
    {
       class cc{
           public void dd()
              {
                 System.out.println("hello");   
              }
     } 
       new cc().dd();
    }
```